# Can VBA predict a n-th row and also copy the parameters?

Tags: vba, excel

```
A      B

1.     count
2.     _
3.     Count
4.     _
5.     _
6.     Labels
7.     2
8.     3
9.     5
10.    6
11.    shorttest
12.    midtest
13.    longtest
14.    coldtest
15.    hottest
16.    Resultant
```

I have tried to write out a code and am not very sure if it will work.

What i would like to do now is, I would like to copy A11 to G16 into another worksheet, they can be considered as test perimeters.

But there are times when some of the parameters are missing like longtest and coldtest is missing since the tests are not done. Shown in the following

```
A      B

1.     count
2.     _
3.     Count
4.     _
5.     _
6.     Labels
7.     2
8.     3
9.     5
10.    6
10.    shorttest
11.    midtest
12.    hotest
13.    Resultant
```

And there can also be test parameters such as night_test, morning_test etc...

Do take note that, these readings are obtained from tests done and are added into the page manually. And also "Resultant" will always be at the last row.

I was wondering if VBA could process the n-th "A_" value (i.e. A1, A2,A3...An) instead of just A11 as shown in my code? And can it copy the test parameters (for this example shorttest to resultant)

My codes are as follows:

```
Sub macro1()
    Dim valuecell As Range
    Dim irow As Range
    Dim iCol As Range

    For irow = 1 To 6
        For iCol = 1 To 1
            If valuecell = "1" Or _
              valuecell = "2" Or _
              valuecell = "3" Or _
              valuecell = "4" Or _
              valuecell = "5" Or _
              valuecell = "6" Then
                irow = irow + 1
            ElseIf valuecell = "Resultant" Then
                Range("A11:G13").Copy Destination:=Worksheets("sheet4").Range("A11")
            Else
                irow = irow + 1
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I am sorry but I didn't understand your question. What did you intend to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You question is rather unclear, but if I understand correctly, you want to copy everything that comes after the numbers 1 to 6 and up to "Resultant", to another sheet. The following code will do this.

```
Sub macro1()
    Dim valuecell As Range
    Dim irow As Long
    Dim iFirstRowToCopy As Long
    Dim iLastRowToCopy As Long
    Dim vValuesToCopy As Variant

    irow = 1 ' Initialise

    'Loop until you meet numbers between 1 and 6
    Do
        Set valuecell = Sheet1.Cells(irow, 1)
        If valuecell >= 1 And valuecell <= 6 Then
            Exit Do
        End If
        irow = irow + 1
    Loop

    'Loop until you get out of numbers between 1 and 6
    Do
        Set valuecell = Sheet1.Cells(irow, 1)
        If valuecell >= 1 And valuecell <= 6 Then
            'Do nothing
        Else
            iFirstRowToCopy = irow ' Found the first row to copy
            Exit Do
        End If
        irow = irow + 1
    Loop

    'Loop until you meet "Resultant"
    Do
        Set valuecell = Sheet1.Cells(irow, 1)
        If valuecell = "Resultant" Then
            iLastRowToCopy = irow ' Found the last row to copy
            Exit Do
        End If
        irow = irow + 1
    Loop

    'Read the values that need copying
    vValuesToCopy = Sheet1.Cells(iFirstRowToCopy, 1) _
        .Resize(iLastRowToCopy - iFirstRowToCopy + 1, 1)
    'Write the values to the destination sheet
    Worksheets("Sheet4").Cells(iFirstRowToCopy, 1) _
        .Resize(iLastRowToCopy - iFirstRowToCopy + 1, 1) = vValuesToCopy
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm glad you understood what i meant! I will try and use this code! Thank you!

Comment: +1 for getting it in 1st go even when the question was unclear :)

Comment: @Jean-François Corbett: I absolutely know what you mean :P

Comment: @Jean-François Corbett: You can start to see where people want to go with something even if the explaination is missing a bunch of key details. +1 indeed

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett: I would like to check with you, if it is possible to paste the copied result onto 1st row 1st column of sheet 4? What should be modified? Thanks!

Comment: @user1204868: What do *you* think? Have a shot at it and we can fix it if it doesn't work.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett, hi , i have made some changes to your answer.. do let me know if it is the corerct 1.

Comment: If you have changes to your question, then please edit your question (showing what you've tried) and don't edit my answer. I can see that you have a proposed solution. Have you tried it? Does it work?